Kerberos \ AD auth issue on an Azure Storage account
Hoping this is a simple one but i'm banging my head against a brick wall.
Our environment is moving to cloud \ AAD Only services but we still have a number of hybrid \ AD only systems.
We have a Server 2022 application server in Azure which is AD Joined
We have a new AVD host pool which is AADJ only
Kerberos auth to the server is working perfectly.
The curve ball is the azure file that this is using. It is set up for kerberos auth and on the AVD system works fine. On the app server however it will not allow access or authenticate.
Tried the kerberos cloud reg key which seems to do nothing other than prevent the authentication box being displayed. Just says it cant find the resource.
Without this enabled we get the auth box but no creds work.
The previous version of this software used an ad auth account which works on the server but doesn't on the AVD or when the kerberos reg key is added to the app server.
In an ideal world I would like to be able to sign into both the old  Azure AD file share and the Kerberos auth file share on the same box but this doesn't seem possible at the moment.
Hope this makes sense to someone because it's driving me mad.
